# Wrong index after re-ordering datagrid rows

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a `DataTable` bound to a `DataGridView`. When I re-order the rows, the column index of the string I'm looking for gets messed up.

I get the index of the Serial Num column... this works, even after I've moved it.

```
Dim snIndex As Integer = asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.[Single](Function(c) c.Header.ToString() = "Serial Num").DisplayIndex
```

Then I direct cast the row i'm clicking

```
Dim item As DataRowView = DirectCast(asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
```

Then I grab the string of the cell in the Serial Num column.

```
 Dim sn As String = item.Row(snIndex)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4EqC.png

This of course doesn't work, and when I re-order my serial number column to lets say... index 0, it grabs the asset ID cell string. I'm trying to find the Serial number of whatever row I click on, no matter where the serial number column is.

Any ideas on how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a column of a `DataRowView` by its name rather than the index:

```
Dim item As DataRowView = DirectCast(asset_MasterDataGrid.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
Dim sn As String = item("Serial Num")
```

This should work provided that you know the name of the serial number column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are clicking a datagrid header to reorder your selection, the linked data will not be reordered, the index will still be the same, the selected item will be what you select, but its index in the DataTable has not changed

to seach column index try this (C#)

```
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0, i < asset_MasterDataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
    if (((DataColumn)asset_MasterDataGrid).ColumnName == "Serial Num")
    {
        index = i;
         break;
    }
```

obvious this is your **column** with your serial.

Now to get your value with this serial number you need to seach in your DataGrid for it (not in your dataTable)

Comment: This is telling me why it's happening, which is nice, and what I figured it was doing... however, doesn't really help me fix the issue.

Comment: I've already got the serial number column index, that's not the issue. I still can't figure out how to grab the correct string after I've moved the SN column.